# How to view object code as plain binary

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly

`a.out` file when viewed in a file editor is shown as unprintable characters. Is there a way to view its as plain binary file. I have generated the `a.out` file using gcc. This is for academic purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upon further research, `xxd -b` should do exactly what you need it to. I tested it in the terminal on a small `a.out` file and sure enough it was printed in a binary format.

---

Do you mean viewing it as a sequence of 0s and 1s? `hexdump(1)` should do the trick, but it'll be in hexadecimal.

```
$ hexdump -C /usr/bin/hexdump 
0000000    feca    beba    0000    0300    0001    0700    0080    0300
0000010    0000    0010    0000    5080    0000    0c00    0000    0700
0000020    0000    0300    0000    00a0    0000    b06f    0000    0c00
0000030    0000    1200    0000    0a00    0100    0010    0000    107c
0000040    0000    0c00    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000050    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
```